# Why does "as" does not work on Value types while "is" does?

Tags: c#

'as' operator does not work with value types while 'is' does. why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the `as` operator returns `null` if the type is not matching, and a value type cannot hold a `null` value.

For example

```
double d = myVariable as double;
```

if `myVariable` is not a `double`, d will be `null`, and that is not an appropriate value for a `double`.

Comment: Note that you *can* use `as` with nullable value-types, `double?`, `int?` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Check this: [C# `is` and `as` operators](http://ekrishnakumar.wordpress.com/2006/07/08/c-is-and-as-operators/)

Answer (score 0):

And `as` is different from casting (excelent explanation [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx)).
`as` will never change the representation of the object itself, it will just change the type of the reference, while casting will change the type of the object itself if neccessary.

```
int? i = 3;
double? d = (double?)i;
```

is valid (and working) c# code, while

```
int? i = 3;
double? d = i as double?;
```

errors with "Cannot convert type 'int?' to 'double?' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion"

Comment: Using `as` to convert a null reference to a nullable value-type does change the representation.